# How do I find the index of of the matrix row that meets a certain condition?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have the indices `(Idx = 3, 8, and 10)` of two rows of an `mx3` matrix `A`, with their associated elements as shown in `A` below:

```
A = [7 4 5
     8 4 5
     NaN NaN NaN
     1 4 5
     1 5 5
     7 4 5
     2 4 5
     4 5 7
     2 4 6
     NaN NaN NaN];
```

I would want to extract the row that has the last `all NaNs`; this could occur in any row of matrix A.

Comment: I was expecting `A` to have some `NaN`s for better explanation of your problem. do you want this: `idx=idx(all(isnan(A(idx,:)),2))`; `idx=idx(end)`?

Comment: Well for the given example it is only `A(3,:)` that has all `NaNs`. I guess for a trial one could add `NaNs` at some other rows.

Comment: Please reformulate the question more clearly, I have no idea what you are asking. Provide a simple example which reproduces the behaviour that you do not understand, and what you would expect.

Comment: @SardarUsama your code is fine, only that it returns all positions of the NaNs. I will need only the last position of NaNs. Thanks for your time.

Comment: it does return the last index. You might have missed `idx=idx(end)` in my comment

Comment: What is the meaning of `idx` in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the positions of `NaN`s with [**`isnan`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) and use [**`all`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) to find the rows whose all elements are `NaN`s. Find the elements of `idx` for which the the stated conditions are true and finally get the last element of `idx` that satisfies those conditions.

```
idx=idx(all(isnan(A(idx,:)),2)); %elements of idx for which A has all NaNs
idx=idx(end);                    %last element of idx for which A has all NaNs
```

or if you want a one-liner then use [**`find`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) with the direction as [`'last'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#inputarg_direction):

```
idx=idx(find(all(isnan(A(idx,:)),2),1,'last'));
```

Comment: Oh truly i missed the last part. Thank you so much!